# Actionscript: Can Japanese characters be loaded into a dynamic textbox?

Tags: dynamic, actionscript, textbox

Japanese text won't display in my dynamic textbox.  I tried roman letters and they work fine. I also made sure that the Japanese characters were embedded with the font in the textbox.

What is wrong?

```
display.text = ('私の髪は茶色です。');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your textField is using the embedded font

```
display.embedFonts = true;
```

Comment: and that your font chosen has japaneese characters in it.